# cannot edit stores configuration with config cache enabled, disable yes

Tags: magento2

I am thinking i need to re install magento. It was installed on a subdomian folder with a subdomain, then when we wanted to go live to the tld, had trouble, and ended up just copying the install files and folders to the domain /public_html

if a re install is recommended, is it ok to install in on a subdomain test, then edit base urls and go live with the top level domain?d

Thanks!
Jack

Answer (score 0):

Which steps did you take to begin with?
Using productive or development mode?

First off I'd recommend clearing the cache after you changed the base url (Did you change it directly in the database or via command line?)

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: installed in test.example.com  production mode. changed base urls at /admin123. 
i have been disabling and clearing cache after each change to test. I am just adequately competent at cli and db management.

Comment: Alright. I haven't changed the base url on an production enabled store yet but I assume you'll have to go the full way in order to make it work:
`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`


If you need additional images beside english you will have to add them with the deploy command.
For example with the spanish language:
`php bin/magento setup:static:deploy en_US es_ES`

Comment: are these cli commands? this install is on a cpanel server

Comment: Yes they are.
If you cannot run command line commands you will either have to ask your admin to do it for you, or pregenerate everything on another computer and upload it.

Edit:
Also see Magento Documentation on static file deployment ("Run all Magento CLI commands as the Magento file system owner.") https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

Comment: I do have access to cli using putty. log in as root? and just run these commands? or do i have to edit files?

Comment: Please refrain from using root if not really nessecary.
Run these commands as the user the webserver uses (magento 2 filesystem owner)

There is no need to manually edit any files

Comment: Will these commands work from root? I don't know the magento file system owner process.

Comment: Yes but you will have to reset the owner anyway then...
Just look who is the current owner of the files (`ls -lhap` in magento basedir will give you a nice list of folders/files including the owner and group. I is recommended to use the same user as the current owner. As per usual the owner is the webservers username)

Comment: also, i use cpanel ususally for compiling php, or upgrading to new stable versions. Just want to be careful not to conflict or bring the server down.

Comment: nothing to import : result of 1st command, ran in the home directory of webhost account.

Comment: [alwayscharming@rock6a public_html]$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Proxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec 46.0 Proxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% < 1 sec 50.0 Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% < 1 sec 50.0 MiB
Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.[alwayscharming@rock6a public_html]$

Comment: something changed. I took a 55 minute nap, came back as is, and now i am able to enter stores configuration parameters and they don't disappear upon saving.. I was about to increase the memory to 2G, which i may do anyway. I have been trying to solve this for days.. what do you think made this work now?

Comment: anyway, it's working now for the first time.. i'll check again later and see if it is stable. I never used user to login to cli before.. thanks for your instruction and help. i read, i thought, not to us +1 or thanks in the comments.. i am new and not aware or etiquette. learning..

Comment: Well the memory limit should be at least 768M for production and 2G for test/development according to the manuals. The message "nothing to import" simply means the database scheme is up to date. Did you run the compile command again after it failed? If not it should have not yet generated files and the shop could have some parts not working at all... Beside that I still have the cache itself in mind. Once you change the store configuration it will take some time till it's refreshed. If you not manually clear it after save. About the +1... You usually mark correct answers as "the answer"